# correct href and src values while using apache mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, href, src

I'm trying to make my application URLs friendly using Apache mod_rewrite.
There is an important question in my mind.
What is the correct format of **href** attribute in `<a>` tags?

1. `<a href="/about/">`
2. `<a href="about/">`
3. `<a href="/about">`

What about css, js, and image files ?

1. `<img src="images/photo.jpg">`
2. `<img src="./images/photo.jpg">`
3. `<img src="/images/photo.jpg">`

Comment: Both number 1 and 3 is correct for anchors, number 3 is correct for images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a hard nut to crack because it is completely context driven, they could all mean the same thing or something completely different depending on the context they are being displayed in.

Likely your in your first example 1 and 3 indicated the same locations (/about/index.html and failing that /about/index.php).  2 is subject to where the link is (it is a relative like) so if it appears on http://www.mydomain.com/index.html about is equivalent to 1 and 3 but if it is on on http://www.mydomain.com/services/widget-cleaning it refers to http://www.mydomain.com/services/about/index.html (or .php).

On your second example 1 and 2 are the same (the leading . in the second example means from this directory) whereas example 3 means the images directory in the site root. (i.e. http://www.mydomain.com/images/photo.jpg)

The short answer is you probably mean 1 in the first example and 3 in the second.

Answer (score 0):

For the first example it doesn't matter to mod_rewrite, it will look to match 'about', optionally with a trailing slash.

RewriteRule ^about/?$ about/index.php [NC,L]

Re the second I use absolute paths for images to save some pain, you can also use a rule to ignore images and css/js files.

RewriteRule .(js|css|jpe?g|gif|png)$ - [L]

It's also useful to use a rule to ignore AJAX urls.

RewriteRule ^ajax/(.+)$ - [L]